# jQuery incrementing classname and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I am very new to javascript and I'm learning everyday from your community.
However, I can't find a clean solution for my current problem.

I have a grid of tiles on the first slide of a slideshow, and I want each one to link to the respective slide. For example the tile with classname "linkSlide3" goes to slide "3". Now I want to avoid repeating the following function which is working at the moment:

```
$('.linkSlide3').click(function() {
    $('.slider').mySuperSlider('goTo', 3);
    return false;
});
```

I need to increment from 1 to 20, how can I write it nicely please?

Thank you very much for your help! :-)

Answer (score 5):

For such situations I use data attributes to refer corresponding elements:

```
$('.linkSlide').click(function() {
    $('.slider').mySuperSlider('goTo', $(this).data('slide'));
    return false;
});
```

And in HTML you add `data-slide` attribute to each repeating element:

```
<a class="linkSlide" data-slide="3">...</a>
```

*Here is abstract example of how such a binding can work:* http://jsfiddle.net/rNvKe/

Comment: To use this solution instead of having `.linkSlide1`, `.linkSlide2`, etc. you should have only one `.linkSlide` class for all elements and use `data-attribute` to denote the number.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming your action buttons

> .linkSlide1
>    .linkSlide2
>    .linkSlide3
>    .etc...

you can just do

> .linkslide

and make sure that there's no other element inside the parent of your buttons, 
that way your `.linkslide` elements will be organized by `index` from `0` to `19` (for 20 buttons).
Than go grab the `.index()` of the clicked button and send it to `.superSlider( THAT INDEX!! )`.

To animate your slider than you can just **multiply that retrieved index by one-slide-width**:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/afizod/5/edit)**</kbd>

**jQuery:**

```
$('.linkSlide, .back').click(function() {
    var ind = $(this).index()+1; // +1 cause we are already at 0
    if($(this).hasClass('back')) ind = 0; // go to slide index 0
    superSlider( ind ); 
});

function superSlider( ind ){
  var oneSlideWidth = $('.slide').width();
  $('#allSlides').stop().animate({left: -(ind*oneSlideWidth) },700);  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">  
  <div id="allSlides">

    <div class="slide"> <!-- index = 0 -->
        Slide 0
       <button class="linkSlide">Tile index 1</button> <!-- index = 0, add 1-->
       <button class="linkSlide">Tile index 2</button> <!-- index = 1, add 1 -->
       <button class="linkSlide">Tile index 3</button> <!-- index = 2, add 1 -->
    </div>

    <div class="slide"> <!-- index = 1 -->
      Slide 1
      <button class="back">Back to 0</button>      
    </div>

    <div class="slide"> <!-- index = 2 -->
      Slide 2
      <button class="back">Back to 0</button>      
    </div>


    <div class="slide"> <!-- index = 3 -->
      Slide 3
      <button class="back">Back to 0</button>      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:95px;
  background:#eee;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;  
}
#allSlides{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:9999px;
  height:95px;
}

.slide{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:95px;
  float:left;
}
```

Explore the jQuery methods I used:

http://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/index/
http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/
http://api.jquery.com/width/
http://api.jquery.com/stop/
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

This was my first question on this website, and I didn't expect so many detailed answers… so quickly!
So thanks to all of you, for your time, skills and kindness!

I followed dfsq answer and it worked fine :-)

HTML:

```
    <div class="linkSlide" data-slide="1"></div>
    <div class="linkSlide" data-slide="2"></div>
    <div class="linkSlide" data-slide="3"></div>
    etc… until 20
```

JS:

```
$('.linkSlide').click(function() {
    $('.slider').mySuperSlide('goTo', $(this).data('slide'));
    return false;
});
```